# Compilation error on oracle trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, compiler-errors

I have a table that has employees (oracle SQL), where each employee has a manager (which is represented as a fk of another employee). I want to create a trigger that when an employee is deleted, all employees that have his key in their manager field have their manager changed to null (or -1, or some reserved value). I'm having some trouble figuring out what's wrong with my current code:

EDIT:
I fixed up most of my code, and I was going about it the wrong way. I used the ON DELETE option that was suggested and now everything works fine. Here's my code:

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeA
(
    employeeID integer,
    firstName varchar (255),
    lastName varchar (255),
    phone integer,
    jobTitle varchar (255),
    payGrade integer,
    fk_EmployeeemployeeID integer,
    PRIMARY KEY(employeeID),
    FOREIGN KEY(fk_EmployeeemployeeID) REFERENCES EmployeeA (employeeID) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEEA VALUES (1, null, 'Powell', 0, 'President', 100, 1);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEEA VALUES (2, null, 'Hicke', 0, 'Dean (Natural Science)', 100, 1);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEEA VALUES (3, null, 'Fenves', 0, 'Dean (Engineering)', 100, 1);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEEA VALUES (4, null, 'Porter', 0, 'Chairman (Computer Science)', 100, 2);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEEA VALUES (5, null, 'Beckner', 0, 'Chairman (Mathematics)', 100, 2);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEEA VALUES (6, null, 'Miranker', 0, 'Professor (Computer Science)', 100, 4);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEEA VALUES (7, null, 'Mok', 0, 'Professor (Computer Science)', 100, 4);
DELETE FROM employeeA WHERE lastName = 'Porter';
```

Comment: I believe you would get another error even if it could be compiled, Oracle complains that you can not update the same table which trigger is on it. Why don't you update NEW record?

Comment: because we shouldn't care about the new record. The new record is the new manager row, but we want the employees that report to the manager to have their manager field set to null.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment where you have to use a trigger?  Or would you be able to use the `on delete` property of the foreign key?

Comment: I can use whatever I want, I just thought using a trigger would be easier. I'm pretty noob so I don't know what you mean by the "on delete" property

Comment: JUST CHANGED EVERYTHING. I solved the problem with your on delete suggestion. +1 to you if i could give it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use a trigger here.  Use the `on delete` property of the foreign key.  When you define the foreign key constraint, you can specify that you want it to set the child rows to `NULL` when the parent row is deleted.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create table employee2(
  2    employee_id number primary key,
  3    manager_id  number,
  4    employee_first_name varchar(30),
  5    constraint fk_manager_emp
  6      foreign key( manager_id )
  7      references employee2( employee_id )
  8      on delete set null
  9* )
SQL> /

Table created.
```

If we add a boss, a manager (who reports to the boss), and an employee (who reports to the manager)

```
SQL> insert into employee2( employee_id, manager_id, employee_first_name )
  2    values( 1, null, 'Boss' );

1 row created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  insert into employee2( employee_id, manager_id, employee_first_name )
  2*   values( 2, 1, 'Emp1' )
SQL> /

1 row created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  insert into employee2( employee_id, manager_id, employee_first_name )
  2*   values( 3, 2, 'Emp2' )
SQL> /

1 row created.
```

then when we delete the manager, the employee's `manager_id` automatically gets set to `NULL`

```
SQL> delete from employee2
  2   where employee_first_name = 'Emp1';

1 row deleted.

SQL> select *
  2    from employee2
  3   where employee_first_name = 'Emp2';

EMPLOYEE_ID MANAGER_ID EMPLOYEE_FIRST_NAME
----------- ---------- ------------------------------
          3            Emp2
```